# Vite for Nuxt.js : Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/chunk-ZLOXRQYH.js.map'

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vite

I am using [Nuxt Vite](https://vite.nuxtjs.org/) in a SSR project

everything rendered correctly when I enter the page by typing the url in browser address bar, but when I try to go to other page by click `<nuxt-link/>` inside of the website, errors appear in terminal

> ERROR  12:29:42 PM [vite] error while updating dependencies:              12:29:42
> Error: ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/project/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/chunk-ZLOXRQYH.js.map'
> at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1035:3)
> at emptyDir (/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cb562f8f.js:4293:25)
> at optimizeDeps (/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cb562f8f.js:65308:9)
> at Timeout.rerun [as _onTimeout] (/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cb562f8f.js:68848:67)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)

Also in browser consloe:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

But once I use webpack instead of vite, errors gone, everythings go well.

I am sorry that I can't provide a smallest errors reproduction, because it only occured when the project is not samll and also I have no idea what caused it.

I try to run `sudo npm run dev`, but errors still exist.

How can I figure out what caused this, and how to solve it?

Comment: It's supposed to be `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` or `<NuxtLink />`, the in-between is not correct. As shown in the styleguide: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended Also, using `sudo` with `npm` is a really bad idea. Maybe a restart of the app may be a good idea too. The MIME type error is suggesting a different kind of error tho.

Comment: @kissu Thank you so much for this and the previous! `<nuxt-link/>` is just an exmaple to describe the errors, it's not the real code.